# Best technique for real-time communication apart from socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

**Note:** I know this is the duplicate question is been asked many a times but all the answers which I got on internet are quite old. I am sure there must be many advancement in technology.

So I am working on a real time data transmission application in node.js, I want to implement the best technology in the market.

So I want suggestion which is the best library that can be used for this.

My work:

I have read about the following libraries which are present in the market but not sure which should be best to use. We have **socket.IO** which is pretty good but do we have any other solution better then socket.IO for real time data transmission.

1. Socket.IO [Library](https://socket.io/)
2. Faye [Library](https://faye.jcoglan.com/node.html)
3. Primus [Primus](https://github.com/primus/primus)